# How to initialize the structure member with using pointer?

Tags: c

I have below code. In below code the value `5` gets stored in variable `a`(i.e `abc.a`). But I would like to intialize the value in `c` (i.e `abc.c`). How to do that? My requirement is to fill the data for `c` not for `a`.

```
typedef struct abc
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}abc;
typedef struct def{
    int *ptr;
    abc strpt;
}def;
typedef struct xyz{
int *pointer;
}xyz;
int main()
{
    int *temp, tmp;
    abc* ab;
    tmp = 5;
    temp = &tmp;
    ab = (abc*)malloc(sizeof(abc));
    xyz *x = (xyz*)malloc(sizeof(xyz));
    def *de = (def*)malloc(sizeof(def));
    x->pointer = (xyz*)temp;
    ab = (abc*)x->pointer;


    return 0;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Why did you tag this C++? Are you aware that C and C++ are different languages?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Because I need to call the function from `C++` and the called function is in `C` language

Comment: Yes, if you use, c++, you should use `new` instead of old old `malloc()`

Comment: You are doing really bad things here: You just overwrite the pointer to the newly allocated instance of xyz with the pointer to your stack(!) variable tmp. Seems to me totally wrong. So maybe you can hand some information why you do it that complicated?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak that makes no difference. The code is in C, right? I mean, you're running the program, say, on a Windows 32 bit machine, but you didn't tag it as `windows` or `32bit`, did you?

Comment: @junix: My project has that complicated code

Comment: is this homework? Not necessarily a problem if it is, but please tag it if it is.

Comment: @Vicky: It's not homework, it is a problem I am facing in my project

Comment: OK. If it's a "real" (non-homework) project, why do you "have" to use pointers to fill the data? Help me out here.

Comment: @Vicky:This pointer fill the complete structure from some where. But in my case I don't have access to that file and all

Comment: So you get your data from a completely different code path & in different format (read: different struct definition, xyz), which you want to type cast to your struct - abc & want to have it filled properly? try interchanging `int a;` & `int c;` in `struct abc` definition ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Affraid some serious lack of understanding pointers manifests in your code. Let me dissect it line by line to make clear where problems occur.

I numbered the statements in order to make easy references, assuming the type declarations as above.

```
int main()
{
    int *temp, tmp;
    abc* ab;
    /* 1 */ tmp = 5;
    /* 2 */ temp = &tmp;
    /* 3 */ ab = (abc*)malloc(sizeof(abc));
    /* 4 */ xyz *x = (xyz*)malloc(sizeof(xyz));
    /* 5 */ def *de = (def*)malloc(sizeof(def));
    /* 6 */ x = (xyz*)temp;
    /* 7 */ ab = (abc*)x;

    return 0;
}
```

First of all: You never clean up the memory allocated in 3, 4 and 5. Even for a simple test program, you should always take care of stuff like this.

Your first problem is line 6 where you blindly cast a pointer to an object of type int (4 bytes in memory) into a pointer to a structure of type xyz (4 or 8 bytes in memory, different type). What you do here is a complicated way to write `x = (xyz*)&tmp;`.

An action like that leads to following serious problems:

1. You just allocated memory in line 4. Now you overwrite this pointer with a pointer to your stack variable. Therefore you can't free the allocated memory anymore ==> Memory leak
2. Your newly assigned pointer to the stack variable becomes invalid after exiting the scope and can cause undefined behaviour.
3. Any write attempt to elements of x after line 6 can lead to corruption of the stack (and therefore undefined behaivour) due to a possible size mismatch of elements.

By line 7 you get the same problems again and even worse. The estimated sizeof(abc) is possibly 12 bytes. Accessing any element of abc after this line can lead to stack corruption again.

I still don't understand what you really are looking for but if you "have to" initialize a structure element through pointers there are a several ways:

If the struct ist known you can do it like this:
    abc * ab = malloc(sizeof(abc));

```
if (ab != NULL) {
    ab->c = 5;

    // -- do other stuff

    free(ab); ab = NULL;
}
```

If you need a pointer to the element 'c' you can do it like this:

```
int * c_ptr = NULL;
abc * ab = malloc(sizeof(abc));

if (ab != NULL) {
    c_ptr = &(ab->c);
    *c_ptr = 5;

    //-- do other stuff
    free(ab); ab = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for this:

```
abc s;
s.c = 5;
```

That makes `c` 5. Or you could do thos:

```
abc s = {0,0,5};
```

That means, the first two members are initialized to `0`, and third one (which is `c`) is initialized to `5`.

Or if you've pointer, then you can do this:

```
abc *p = malloc(etc);
p->c = 5;
```

But then avoid using pointers and `malloc`. Use it when you *really* need them. In your code, I don't see any reason why you would need it. Use automatic variables, not pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to add this before return in your main() to get what you need.

```
ab->c = *(x->pointer);
```